# Invoking WCF service with PHP (with federated security)

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, soap

I’m trying to invoke a WCF service (.NET) from PHP. It’s a little more complicated than just using a `SoapClient` since the service uses a `WS2007FederationHttpBinding` to authenticate.

Here’s the code I’m using at the moment. I haven’t even added credentials as I’m not sure how, but regardless, I’m not even at the point where I’m getting access denied errors.

```
$wsdl = "https://slc.centershift.com/sandbox40/StoreService.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array(
         //'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2 // default 1.1, but this gives 'Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers'
        ));
$params = array();
$params['SiteID'] = 123;
$params['GetPromoData'] = false;

$ret = $client->GetSiteUnitData(array('GetSiteUnitData_Request'=>$params));
print_r($ret);
```

1. Which WSDL should I be pointing to?

   - `https://slc.centershift.com/Sandbox40/StoreService.svc?wsdl`
     Seems to be very short, but includes a reference to (note the `wsdl0`) `https://slc.centershift.com/Sandbox40/StoreService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0`
   - `https://slc.centershift.com/Sandbox40/StoreService.svc?singleWsdl`
     Seems to have everything in it.
2. Do I need to specify SOAP 1.2? When I do, I get a connection timeout (`[HTTP] Error Fetching http headers`). When I don’t, the default of SOAP 1.1 is used and I get a `[HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'`. Is this because I’m not authenticated yet, or because I’m using the wrong SOAP version?
3. How to authenticate in PHP? Here’s the corresponding .NET/C# code. Do I need to somehow put these as SOAP headers? Or am I thinking about it all wrong, and I need to do some kind of authentication before I even call the method (from what I read, I’m supposed to get a token back and then use it for all future method calls – I think I see an example of this in [an answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637585).
   [image]

If I call `$client->__getFunctions()`, using either WSDL and either SOAP version, I’m getting a valid list of all functions, so I assume either of these is fine and my real issue is the authentication.

Other programmers I’ve talked to had spent time trying to get this to work, but gave up and instead implemented a proxy in .NET. They pass their parameters from PHP to their own unsecured .NET service, which in turn calls this secure service. It works, but seems crazily inefficient to me, and counter-productive, as the purpose of WCF is to support all types of clients (even non-HTTP ones!).

I’ve read [How to: Create a WSFederationHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347982(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN, but it didn’t help.

Comment: Either ?wsdl or ?singleWsdl will be fine. The former references multiple documents split up by purpose, the latter has it all in one place. The wsdl does specify the soap version being used so it seems odd that after it has downloaded the wsdl it still needs to be told which soap version to use. I would suggest the library is immature/poor quality if this basic info needs to be provided in addition to the wsdl and I wouldn't expect you to get federation working with it. I suggest find a different/better soap library.

Comment: @MattC Thanks for the comment. Good to know about the WSDL, but hopefully the soap library isn't an issue (it's the native PHP one). I checked out nuSoap but didn't look like it'd offer any advantages.

Comment: I really don’t want to sound snarky, @ShaneN, but being built into PHP is not a warranty of quality. See e.g. the crappy `mail()`. Have not worked with SOAP from PHP, so I cannot help.

Comment: I tried to help at least by editing the question to be easier to read. Please, replace the code screenshot with a code block with the actual code. Posting code as screenshot prevents others from fiddling with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use this URL for WSDL https://slc.centershift.com/Sandbox40/StoreService.svc?singleWsdl. This WSDL has all definitions.
2. You have to use 1.2 because this webservice works with SOAP 1.2 version. I tried it with 1.1 and 1.2 and both of them gived error. 1.1 is version error, 1.2 is timeout error. I think there is an error at this test server. I used it with svcutil to generate code but it gived error too. Normaly it should get information and generate the code example to call service.
3. Normally you can add authenticate parameters with SoapHeader or directly add to options in SoapClient consruct (if service authentication is basic authentication). I write below code according to your screenshot. But it gives timeout after long wait.

   ```
   $wsdl = "https://slc.centershift.com/sandbox40/StoreService.svc?wsdl";
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1,'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));

   $security = array(
   'UserName' => array(
       'UserName'=>'TestUser',
       'Password'=>'TestPassword',
       'SupportInteractive'=>false
    )
   );

   $header = new SoapHeader('ChannelFactory','Credentials',$security, false);
   $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);



   $params = array();
   $params['SiteID'] = 100000000;
   $params['Channel'] = 999;
   try {
       $ret = $client->GetSiteUnitData($params);
       print_r($ret);
   }catch(Exception $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
   }
   ```

   `__getFunctions` works, because it prints functions defined in WSDL. There is no problem with getting WSDL information at first call. But real problem is communication. PHP gets WSDL, generates required SOAP request then sends to server, but server is not responding correctly. SOAP server always gives a response even if parameters or request body are not correct.

   You should communicate with service provider, I think they can give clear answer to your questions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Unfortunately the service provider is not willing to provide help. They claim their service is working for .NET clients, so they have no reason to investigate it not working for any other client types. Essentially, they're forcing us to use a Microsoft stack, which we're not open to doing just for them.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with consuming .NET WS from PHP before I believe you would need to create objects from classes in PHP that matches the names that .NET is expecting. The WSDL should tell you the types it is expecting. I hope this assist with your path forward!

Answer (score 0):

If the SOAP call works from a C# application, you could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) (with the filter `ip.dst == 204.246.130.80`) to view the actual request being made and then construct a similar request from php.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15363681) to see how you can do a custom SOAP call.

There's also the option of doing raw curl requests, since it might be easier to build your xml body, but then you would have to parse the response yourself with simplexml.

Comment: I tried that, but the request is all done over SSL, so any payload of the message is encrypted. There's a way to load a cert so you can decrypt it, and I tried it, but didn't work for me (I think I needed their private key, which I did not have)

Comment: If it doesn't work on a http connection, then the easiest way to view the packets is to set a proxy for the connection and use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-traffic-recording) as a proxy to capture and view the data.